# Putting radio button next to flexible text(sencha touch)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am currently building a Sencha Touch 2 application and I am trying to do the following:[Link to what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CqGs.png)

I have tried alot of things including the following

- Using the radio button label property and aligned it to the right, doing this results in a non-flexible text
- Giving the radio button a static width(30px to be exact) and having the text next to it in a hbox, but I am having problems vertically aligning the text

Comment: You should describe what you want to accomplish in the body of your post so that your question can stand on its own without an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if I understood your question correctly, you can quite easily produce such a view with the labelWidth, labelWrap and labelAlign-properties. See the example below:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
fullscreen: true,
defaults: {
    labelWidth: '85%',
    labelWrap: true,
    labelAlign: 'right'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'field',
        value: '1',
        label: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vulputate arcu non nunc congue, a malesuada purus volutpat. Nunc id.',
        checked: true,
        labelWrap: true
    },
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'field',
        value: '2',
        label: 'Hello World this is a small text.'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        name : 'field',
        value: '3',
        label: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vulputate arcu non nunc congue, a malesuada purus volutpat. Nunc id.'
    }
]
```

});

You can define your label width according to your environment, 85% was a good value to view it in the simulator in the  [Sencha Touch Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Radio) Of course there is Sencha Touch-specific styling applied, so it does not look exactly like your example.